# "ArgumentError Exception: Unknown key" with a find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a coupon system, and I'm trying to get the `coupon` object with the method `find_by`:

```
Coupon.find_by_coupon(params[:coupon])
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError Exception: Unknown key: coupon
```

I'm sure `params[:coupon]` is right:

```
(rdb:1) eval params[:coupon]
{"coupon"=>"100"}
```

I have the following model:

```
# Table name: coupons
#
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  coupon          :string(255)
#  user_id         :integer
```

---

UPDATE:

It's working if I put `Coupon.find_by_coupon(params[:coupon][:coupon])` instead of `Coupon.find_by_coupon(params[:coupon])`.

Here the code with the form in my view:

```
<%= semantic_form_for Coupon.new, url: payment_summary_table_offers_path(@booking_request) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :coupon, :as => :string, :label => false, no_wrapper: true %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :button, :label => t(:button_use_coupon), no_wrapper: true,
    button_html: { value: :reply, :disable_with => t(:text_please_wait) } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This should work. Can you post the full stack trace of this error?

Comment: Oooh do you have a model `Coupon` having an attribute named `coupon` also? Try to rename your column `coupon_code`

Comment: Do you try to set the value(100) direct. to see if the error is somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe your Hash is containing your coupon object, and to access to the coupon attribute you should do `params[:coupon][:coupon]`. Have you tried that ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji it's working and Festado's solution is also working !

So, any idea why ? This is crazy (I updated my original post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3, I advise you to find object using this method:

```
# equivalent of find_all
Coupon.where(:coupon => params[:coupon]) # => Returns an array of Coupons
# equivalent of find :first
Coupon.where(:coupon => params[:coupon]).first # => Returns a Coupon or nil
```

Try to do a `params.inspect` to see exactly how is made your Hash. I think it is built like this:

```
{ :coupon => { :coupon => '100' } }
```

If it is, you should use `params[:coupon][:coupon]` to get the String '100'

**Following your update:**

`semantic_form_for` is creating the form for you, as you give him a `Coupon.new` it will build the params this way:

```
params = {
  :coupon => { :attribute_1 => 'value_1', :attribute_2 => 'value_2' }
}
```

If you prefer to use the find_by method:

```
Coupon.find_by_coupon(params[:coupon][:coupon]) # => Returns a Coupon or raise a RecordNotFound error
```

Or with the where method:

```
Coupon.where(:coupon => params[:coupon][:coupon]).first # => Returns a Coupon or nil
```

Comment: Why is this way to do it better than find_by ?

Comment: Thanks ! Since the form will contain only one coupon at the time, what should I specify to semantic_form_for to send only one coupon instead of an array of coupons.

Comment: It is not sending an array of Coupons to semantic_form_for. It is just passing only one Coupon object. Then it "scopes" the attributes in the params[:coupon], representing a Hash of attributes for the Coupon.new object.